# How to install wp cli on mac

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I am running this command on my mac machine:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
```

But I got this error:

> Warning: Failed to create the file wp-cli.phar: Read-only file system

What should I do?

Comment: In what directory are you calling this command? What does `pwd` and what does `whoami` return you? Is this a company's Mac? Do you have an admin account? You normally should be able to switch to your home directory at least (`cd ~`) and run the above command. And after that the rest from https://wp-cli.org/#installing

Comment: OH this `cd ~` help me :)